# how to create folders and sub folders according to depth value

Tags: node.js, directory, tree

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhtAR.png) At depth 0, create a folder named 0, and create a file in it with its relative path as the content.
At depth 1: besides what should be done with depth 0, create two subfolders named 0 and 1 and create a file to save its path in both respectively.
At depth 2: besides what should be done at the depth 1, create subfolders in folders created at depth 1, and name them as 0, 1, 2, and create files following the same rule.
At depth N: Same rules.

i tried this but I don't think this is the right answer?

```
const fs = require("fs");

const createPathForDepth = (depth) => {
  if (depth <= -1) return console.log("done");
  let tmp = depth;
  let relativePath;
  const path = `./tmp/${depth}`;

  try {
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(path);
      while (tmp > -1) {
        relativePath = `${path}/${tmp}`;
        fs.mkdirSync(relativePath);
        console.log("folder created", relativePath);
        fs.writeFileSync(
          `${relativePath}/${tmp}.txt`,
          `relativePath = ${relativePath}/${tmp}.txt`
        );
        console.log("file created", tmp, ".txt");
        tmp--;
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  depth--;
  createPathForDepth(depth);
};
```

Comment: Will be really helpful if you could add any visual or folder structure to follow?

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: I don't quite follow the visual or the description. Could you create a few sample directories and run `tree` to show the desired structure for a given `depth` call? Thanks.

Comment: A question about the same structure was [asked earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67597976/tree-generation-algorithm/67602521#67602521).

Comment: *"but I don't think this is the right answer"*: you are not sure? What does the script do? Does it produce the expected output or not? Should be easy to check...